# Bug importing with openxlsx2 in R?

Tags: r, excel, import, openxlsx2

I find `openxlsx2` a very interesting package, it's very useful how you can import a workbook keeping styles.

I just wondering if it is a bug or I'm doing something wrong for the very simple task of importing an excel workbook with `openxlsx2::wb_load`. I just want to import first sheet as in `openxlsx::read.xlsx(..., sheet = 1)`.

According to `openxlsx2` documentation `sheet`: *if this is applied, only the selected sheet will be loaded. This can be a numeric, a string or NULL*

```
library(openxlsx2)

> openxlsx2::wb_load("example.xlsx")
A Workbook object.
 
Worksheets:
 Sheets: ES FR UK 
 Write order: 1, 2, 3
```

I *almost* get same result if I do:

```
> openxlsx2::wb_load("example.xlsx", sheet = 1)
A Workbook object.
 
Worksheets:
 Sheets: ES FR UK 
 Write order: 1, 2, 3
```

It still imports all sheets, though data in sheets 2 and 3 has been removed. I want to import only sheet 1.

I have also tried `openxlsx2::wb_load("example.xlsx", sheet = "ES")` with no result.

Comment: I think this question is more suitable at https://github.com/JanMarvin/openxlsx2/issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your interest in `openxlsx2`. This works as expected. Only a single sheet is imported, but the other sheets remain in the workbook, because on load we do not mess with any of the other internal files of the workbook. This argument was intended for use in `wb_to_df()`/`read_xlsx()` when used with the `sheet` argument when it's not required to load unwanted worksheets.

You can remove unwanted worksheets with `openxlsx2::wb_remove_worksheet()`.

If you have a suggestion how to improve the documentation please open a pull request or raise an issue on github. And yes, this would have been a nice question for our githubs discussion section.